# eclipse: strange background color highlighting

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse is always good for a surprise.

After I had a look into the debug view, I noticed that a previous debug run still had an active thread. So I clicked the red square to stop it.

All of a sudden, the respective java code in the editor(s) gained some fancy background colors, light green, yellow and a slightly dark shade of pink. Some lines (especially those without code) still have the previous white background color.

It does not look like a bug but rather like a feature that I have never seen before.

What is it, what is it good for and how can I switch between this strange highlighting and normal background?

Comment: Sounds like you launched it with Code Coverage, but without a picture, who can tell? Are there any code coverage views that are available and now populated?

Comment: Yes, you got it! And when I got to the coverage view and delete the entries (using the grey double-x icon) the highlighting is back to standard. I still don't know how I accidentally did run that with coverage, though. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you launched it with Code Coverage by accident. Are there any code coverage views that are available and now populated that you can clear?

Comment: I think you have enabled "Coverage As" option. Just go to "Coverage" tab and delete the project from the "Coverage" tab, then your background color (pink or other color) will be removed.